# Print an array of letters/ numbers using 32bit assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, ollydbg

```
 litere times 255 db 0 ;letters array
 dim_sir_litere db 0 ;this will tell me how many letters i have in my array

mov [dim_sir_litere],EDI   ; the length of letters array
```

;trying to print all letters from array but it is not working

```
mov ECX,[dim_sir_litere] ;this will have the lenght of my letters array

mov ESI,0  ;this will be the index that i will use
```

;in this loop i want to print all the characters from the litere array

```
       afisare_litere:
                   push ECX ;keep ECX value
                   mov EAX,dword [litere+ESI] ;put in EAX the value from ESI index 
                   inc ESI ;mov index to the next position
                   push dword EAX  
                   push dword format_caracter ;the format is %c
                   call [printf]
                   add esp,4*2
                   pop ECX
         loop afisare_litere
```

The actual problem is it that after i run the code its not printing something, is doesn't print anynthing
I use this code to put letters in array:

```
mov [litere+EBX],AL
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that `litere db 0` only reserves 1 byte of space, but `[litere+EBX]` can access outside of that.  Other than than, this isn't a [mcve] (not very minimal), and "not working" isn't a sufficient description of the problem, and you don't explain exactly what it should do.

Comment: Also, if this is NASM, `'\n'` is a literal backslash and n.  C escapes are only interpreted inside backticks `

Comment: i used and litere times 255 db 0, but with the same result

Comment: So use a debugger, and/or reduce this to an actual [mcve] of just a few instructions that don't do what you expect.  (e.g. take input from a fixed string so you can remove the fread parts)

Comment: Alright, i will try that, thank you

Comment: @PeterCordes can you please take a look now?

Comment: Looks somewhat reasonable, now it's minimal but no longer complete.  There's no declaration for the data like `dim_sir_litere`. And you still don't say *how* it fails.  Does it crash?  If so, probably `dim_sir_litere` is only 1 byte or something, but you're loading 4 bytes into ECX.  (Or it's an equ but you're using `[]`) The fact that you load 4 unaligned bytes from the array when you only want 1 character is fine; passing a `char` function arg does use a 32-bit stack slot, and the `%c` format will ignore the high garbage you pushed.  Normally you'd use `movzx eax, dword [litere+esi]` though.

Comment: push/pop ecx inside the loop just so you can use the slow `loop` instruction is silly, though.  You already have ESI as a loop counter; just `cmp esi, [dim_sir_litere]` / `jbe` if you want to use memory, otherwise keep the upper limit in another register.

Comment: I don't know instructions in assembly. I am trying to learn it now, so i expect to make alot of mistakes. I will edit again

Comment: Do you exit without ever printing a newline?  `stdout` is line buffered, so if you don't exit *cleanly*, any still-buffered stdout data will be lost.  Anyway, you should reserve 4 bytes for `dim_sir_litere` because you're loading/storing dwords to it.

Comment: Actually that variable will keep just a number, 3 for example,  it will tell me how many letter i have in that array

Comment: Yeah, I can see from your code what you're doing with it.  You're keeping that number `3` in a 32-bit register, and `mov [dim_sir_litere],EDI` is a 4-byte (dword) store.  That stores outside the single `db 0` you currently have there, stepping on other variables for stores and loading possible garbage for loads.  Oh, are you maybe zeroing your format string with this?

Comment: I read from a file text so i was thinking that i will have a lot of characters there, that's why i use 32, not necessary though
I redeclared it  with dw now

Comment: `dw` is only a word, 16 bits.  `dd` is data dword.

Comment: Anyway i still have a lot to learn. Now i am just trying to figure out why my code doesnt print something from that array. Honestly thank you so much for your time, but i don t understand all the explanations, i am just like a child who is trying to learn programming . Thank you again!